# Pagination with a for loop getting startpage issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, pagination, extension-methods

i have an extension method that does the pagination. There are 23 entries in the directory so 3 pages,

my controller in short:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? page)
{
  List<ScormModuleInfo> modules = new List<ScormModuleInfo>();

  string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(scormRootDir);

  int totalResults = dirs.Count();
  int pageSize = PageSizeSettings.ScormPackages;
  int totalPages = Math.Max(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((double)totalResults / pageSize)), 1);
  if (page >= 1)
  {
    int startresult = ((Math.Max(1, **page**) - 1) * pageSize) + 1;
    int endresult = Math.Min(startresult + (pageSize - 1), totalResults);
    for (int i = startresult; i <= endresult; i++) 
    {
       //more code
    }
  }
```

in the view:

```
 <div class="actions-left">
   <%= Html.GlobalisedPageLinks(Amico.Web.Mvc.Extensions.Enums.PageLinksFormat.Empty, Model.CurrentPage, Model.PageSize, Model.Total, x => Url.Action("Index", "Scorm", new { area = "Admin", page = x }))%>
 </div>
```

the extension method:

```
public static string GlobalisedPageLinks(this HtmlHelper html, Amico.Web.Mvc.Extensions.Enums.PageLinksFormat format, int currentPage, int pageSize, int totalResults, Func<int, string> pageUrl)
{
  int totalPages = Math.Max(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((double)totalResults / pageSize)), 1);

  int startresult = ((Math.Max(1, currentPage) - 1) * pageSize) + 1;
  int endresult = Math.Min(startresult + (pageSize - 1), totalResults);

  string pagesText = html.Resource(Resources.Global.PageLinks.PageLinksFormatPages, currentPage, totalPages);
  string resultsText = html.Resource(Resources.Global.PageLinks.PageLinksFormatResults, startresult, endresult, totalResults);
  string firstText = html.Resource(Resources.Global.PageLinks.First);
  string previousText = html.Resource(Resources.Global.PageLinks.Previous);
  string nextText = html.Resource(Resources.Global.PageLinks.Next);
  string lastText = html.Resource(Resources.Global.PageLinks.Last);

  return "<span class='page-links'>" + html.PageLinks(format, currentPage, pageSize, totalResults, pageUrl,
    pagesText, resultsText, firstText, previousText, nextText, lastText) + "</span>";
 }
```

I get a red line on Math.Max(1, page) for startresult stating: best overload method is (decimal,decimal) i have some invalid arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
Math.Max(1, page ?? 1)
```

The reason for this is because the `Max` method expects an integer as second argument but you are passing it a nullable integer (your `page` parameter is declared as `int? page`). By using the null coalescing operator (`??`) you are indicating a default value if this parameter is null.